# Socket getInetAddress method override

Tags: java, sockets, methods, overriding

I've been wondering whether it's possible to override Java's `socket.getInetAddress()` method to give different output than ***/IP***. For example, just ***IP***.

I know it's a small change, but custom format is sometimes preferrable.

Can this be done easily or is string manipulation necessary? E.g. using `substring(1)`?

Comment: I don't see that method being declared final, nor is the class declared final, so in theory, yes it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) is not declared `final`, [`Socket.getInetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29) is not `final`, you may override it, even it's not a good idea...

In your implementation of socket `return super.getInetAddress().substring(1);` should work.

You have to provide your own [SocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSocketFactory%28java.net.SocketImplFactory%29) too. Reality a bad idea, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the API classes will never return your version of Socket, so you can't go with override. I suggest a simple utility method which changes the address according to your needs.

Comment: It's the intent of SocketFactory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the interface of the class better suit your needs you can check the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The method you name doesn't produce any output. The format you describe comes from the InetAddress.toString() method. If you don't want that format, don't call that method. There are InetAddress methods to get just the hostname or just the address. Use them. Not a real question.